# How can I set minimum characters limit before @ symbol in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

This is how I am setting errors in my react native registration page. The issue is that it is checking the whole email length but I need to impose character limit of 3 before the @ symbol. What is the best way to do this?

I am using Native Base as my UI kit

```
  const validate = () => {
    let errors = {};
    if (!formData.firstName) errors.firstName = "First name is required";
    if (!formData.lastName) errors.lastName = "Last name is required";
    if (!formData.email) errors.email = "Email is required";
    if (formData.email && formData.email.length < 3) errors.email = "Email is must be 3 characters";
    if (!formData.password) errors.password = "Password is required";
    if (!formData.confirmPassword)
      errors.confirmPassword = "Confirm password is required";
    if (formData.password !== formData.confirmPassword)
      errors.confirmPassword = "Passwords do not match";
    setErrors(errors);
    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `split` function as follows.

```js
if (formData.email && formData.email.includes('@') && formData.email.split('@')[0].length < 3)
```

Comment: Although I would recommend using regex for all kind of validations.